# Is there a way to use regular categories with custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

Is there a way to use regular categories with custom post types?  It seems like there is better functionality and options with regular categories (such as permalink options, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No problem, the categories and tags are also registered as taxonomies that you can pass to the `taxonomies` argument when you call `register_post_type()`. Categories are `category` and tags are `post_tag`. You can also do this later with `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse6098_init', 100 ); // 100 so the post type has been registered
function wpse6098_init()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'your_custom_post_type' );
}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the custom post type posts to show up in filtering results, too?

Comment: @Rasmus: Do you mean on the category pages? Like `/category/banana/`, do you want to see regular posts and your custom post types mixed together? I think you need to hook into the query parameters and add your custom post type to the `post_type` parameter. But it has been a while since I used WordPress, it's not in my active memory now :-)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted. My reason is that otherwise it might be a little hard finding those posts. If someone has the answer in active memory, it would be appreciated -- until then, I'll make do with my (not pretty) work-around!