# How do you add categories to custom post types in WordPress?

Tags: categories

I'd like to be able to have categories of a custom post type, how do you set this up?

update

I want to keep the default categories for regular blog posts, but a separate set of categories just CPT.

Comment: Do you want to use the existing (default) categories, or define a set of categories specific to your CPT?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use regular categories with custom post types?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/is-there-a-way-to-use-regular-categories-with-custom-post-types)

Comment: It's going to be a duplicate of something...the suspense is finding out what!

Comment: I want to keep the default categories for regular blog posts, but a separate set of categories just CPT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `'taxonomies' => array('category')` in your `register_post_type()` function.

Answer (score 3):

- [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
- [`register_taxonomy()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)
- [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type)

Answer (score 2):

You have to register a taxonomy using register_taxonomy or register_taxonomy_for_object_type. The you can use wp_insert_term to insert values for that taxonomy.