# Custom post type category page not working

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives, template-hierarchy

I have a custom post type called 'emp_case-studies'.  Archive and Hierarchical are set to true.

My archive-emp_case-studies.php and single-emp_case-studies.php are performing as expected.  However, when on the archive page, if I click a category link that the post has been given, it goes to e.g. /category/case-studies/engineering/

But I get "Sorry! There are no posts to show at the moment. Please come back later."

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/is-there-a-way-to-use-regular-categories-with-custom-post-types

Comment: Fantastic. That's exactly what I'm after.  Would you be able to post your comment/link as an answer? I'll then accept :)

Comment: If you've already added categories to your custom post type posts, then the issue is not that the taxonomy is not registered for the post type, your problem is that by default the built in category and tag taxonomy queries only include the built in `post` post type, so your solution would actually be this one: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47082/adding-categories-across-posts-and-custom-post-types](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47082/adding-categories-across-posts-and-custom-post-types)

Comment: Thanks Milo. Very useful. In the end I created a custom 'case-studies categories' taxonomy.  It should keep things much tidier as they will be unique to case studies.  But I'll definitely need to implement that solution for other custom post types that share standard post categories. Thanks again.